# list_for_each vs list_for_each_safe, where does the safety come from?

Tags: linked-list, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am not sure how do the *_safe variants of the linked-list traversal code in the Linux kernel provide the extra guarantees for safety.

Anyone can explain that for my simple mind?

Thanks.

Comment: The *safe variants allows you to remove current element in the 'for' loop body without breaking the iteration. It does not guarantee any data integrity on either the list or the current element. One need to protect the critical data before if it is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

From the function's description in [include/linux/list.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.9.11/source/include/linux/list.h#L397):

> list_for_each_safe - iterate over a list safe against removal of list entry

That is during the iteration with `list_for_each_safe` you are allowed to remove currently iterated element. This is not allowed when iterate with simple `list_for_each`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the implementation you'll see that `*_safe` variants use a temporary variable to hold the current list element. Thus, if you choose to remove the current list element while the list is traversed then the integrity of the list - the ability to get the next element from the current one - stays intact. Unsafe variants simply get the next element from the current one, which is an invalid action in the case the current element is removed and most likely freed.